# WARNING: There are some unhandled FacesMessages in spite of <p:message autoUpdate="true">

Tags: jsf, primefaces

hi guys am working on JSF+PrimeFaces project on eclipse and i have the following warning message:

```
WARNING: There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
- The email field is required
- The password field is required
```

here if the source code of my form

```
<p:tab title="#{msg['stu']}">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <div class="card container">
                            <h:form id="formStudent">
                                <fieldset style="width: 300px; margin-left: 20px;">
                                    <legend>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{msg['page.login.student']}" />
                                    </legend>

                                    <div class="p-field p-grid">
                                        <label for="email" class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 100px"><h:outputText
                                                value="#{msg['email']}" /></label>
                                        <div class="p-col">
                                            <p:inputText id="emailStudent" required="true"
                                                requiredMessage="#{msg['required.email']}"
                                                value="#{studentMB.student.email}" type="email" />
                                            <p:message autoUpdate="true" for="emailStudent" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="p-field p-grid">
                                        <label for="password" class="p-col-fixed" style="width: 100px"><h:outputText
                                                value="#{msg['password']}" /></label>
                                        <div class="p-col">
                                            <p:password id="passwordStudent"
                                                requiredMessage="#{msg['required.password']}"
                                                value="#{studentMB.student.password}" toggleMask="true"
                                                redisplay="true" />
                                            <p:message autoUpdate="true" for="passwordStudent" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['login']}"
                                        styleClass="ui-button-raised p-mr-2 ui-button-primary"
                                        action="#{studentMB.login}" />
                                    <br />
                                </fieldset>
                            </h:form>
                        </div>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
```

please how can i fix this? thank

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces and what version of JSF or container?  Also you have `requiredMessage` but not `required="true"` set?

Comment: primefaces 10 and JSF 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autoUpdate` attribute on `p:message` should be removed and instead replaced with:

```html
<p:message for="input-field-id" >
    <p:autoUpdate />
</p:message>
```

Comment: What about the `autoUpdate="true"` on the message components?

Comment: That is why I asked what Version of PF as autoupdate is no longer a property: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/message?id=message it would be 
`<p:message ...>
   <p:autoUpdate />
<p:message>`

Comment: @Melloware I checked pretty much all the PF documentation for the different versions and as far as I could see autoUpdate has never been a valid attribute for `p:message`, only for `p:messages`. My IDE errors the attribute, but the code still runs. I checked. @BalusC the entire form is shown in the snippet. It's two input fields. Sure it could be amended to `update="emailStudentMsg passwordStudentMsg"` without autoUpdate or the solution Melloware has provided could be substituted.  Which would you consider not to be a workaround and I will amend the answer?

Comment: Yep amend the answer to  p:autoUpdate would be good.

Comment: What about `required="true"` missing in the input components?